# How to fix error (cant access lexical declaration Array before initialization ) in react.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I set the array in onchange method and I see it in the console with console.log("array =",array)
with all elemets  but when I want to   delete the duplicate element with Array.from(new Set(array)) method  in the update method
, I find  error in the console ( cant access lexical declaration  Array before initialization  ) !

```js
const [array, setArray] = useState([]); 

const update = (e) =>{ 

  e.preventDefault();  console.log("array =",array);  // = [ 1,  1, 2, 2, 51, 51 ] 
  
  if( array !==undefined){ 
  
    const Array = Array.from(new Set(array));    // error   } }
    
    setarticlesolde((pre) => {      
 
      setArray((pre) => [pre.articleId]);
      return  [... pre];
    })
```

Comment: Not much of your code makes sense. 1) `array` will always have a length of zero so: `if (array.length)` would be better. 2)  Don't assign something to `Array`. Use another variable name. 3) What is `artItem`? 4) What is `setarticlesolde`, and why are you returning an array from it?

Comment: Change `const Array = Array.from(new Set(array));` to `const arr = Array.from(new Set(array));` and see if that fixes the problem

Comment: It workin when I add   var arr =0;
arr = Array.from(new Set(array));

Answer (score 1):

It workin when I change

const Array = Array.from(new Set(array));

to

var arr =0;
arr = Array.from(new Set(array));

you cant use Array like variable because it already defined as existe function in javascript(React.js)

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your code to `const arr = Array.from(new Set(array))`. Array is js inner variable.